# AJAX Post 500 Internal Server Error -

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, internal-server-error

I try to use AJAX to update my database and always get an Internal Server Error (500) I am not sure why this happens, is my data list too long?. On my localhost server it seems to work, but not online.

This is my JS Code:

```
function update_database() {
  var $1Intro = $('#1Intro').val();
  var $1Perspektive = $('#1Perspektive').val();
  var $1Rahmung = $('#1Rahmung').val();
  var $1Montage = $('#1Montage').val();
  var $2Intro = $('#2Intro').val();
  var $2Handlung = $('#2Handlung').val();
  var $2Perspektive = $('#2Perspektive').val();
  var $2Zeit = $('#2Zeit').val();
  var $3Intro = $('#3Intro').val();
  var $3Zeit = $('#3Zeit').val();
  var $3Spielraum = $('#3Spielraum').val();
  var $3Rolle = $('#3Rolle').val();
  var $3Regeln = $('#3Regeln').val();
  var $3Netzwerk = $('#3Netzwerk').val();
  var $01Done = $('#01Done').val();
  var $02Done = $('#02Done').val();
  var $03Done = $('#03Done').val();
  var $0Intro = $('#0Intro').val();
  var $0Fin = $('#0Fin').val();
  var $Position = $('#Position').val();
  var $MobileUser = $('#MobileUser').val();
  var $usr = $('#User').val();

  $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: './gameengine/dataform-to-database.php',
     data: '1_Intro=' + $1Intro + '&1_Perspektive=' + $1Perspektive + '&1_Rahmung=' + $1Rahmung + '&1_Montage=' + $1Montage + '&2_Intro=' + $2Intro + '&2_Handlung=' + $2Handlung + '&2_Perspektive=' + $2Perspektive + '&2_Zeit=' + $2Zeit + '&3_Intro=' + $3Intro + '&3_Zeit=' + $3Zeit + '&3_Spielraum=' + $3Spielraum + '&3_Rolle=' + $3Rolle + '&3_Regeln=' + $3Regeln + '&3_Netzwerk=' + $3Netzwerk + '&0_1Done=' + $01Done + '&0_2Done=' + $02Done + '&0_3Done=' + $03Done + '&0_Intro=' + $0Intro + '&0_Fin=' + $0Fin + '&Position=' + $Position + '&usr=' + $usr + '&MobileUser=' + $MobileUser,
     cache: false,
     error: function(e){
      console.log(e);
      },
      success: function(response){
        //alert(response);
      }
  });
}
```

I hope you have some ideas :)

P.S.: here is my PHP code as well: Tnax for your engagement!

```
<?php
require('../includes/config_o.php');

if(isset($_POST["usr"]))
{

    $stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE userdata SET 1_Intro = :1_Intro, 1_Perspektive = :1_Perspektive, 1_Rahmung = :1_Rahmung, 1_Montage = :1_Montage, 2_Intro = :2_Intro, 2_Handlung = :2_Handlung, 2_Perspektive = :2_Perspektive, 2_Zeit = :2_Zeit, 3_Intro = :3_Intro, 3_Zeit = :3_Zeit, 3_Spielraum = :3_Spielraum, 3_Rolle = :3_Rolle, 3_Regeln = :3_Regeln, 3_Netzwerk = :3_Netzwerk, 0_1Done = :0_1Done, 0_2Done = :0_2Done, 0_3Done = :0_3Done, 0_Intro = :0_Intro, 0_Fin = :0_Fin, Position = :Position, MobileUser = :MobileUser WHERE iUserID = :User');
    $stmt->execute(array(
        ':1_Intro' => $_POST["1_Intro"],
        ':1_Perspektive' => $_POST["1_Perspektive"],
        ':1_Rahmung' => $_POST["1_Rahmung"],
        ':1_Montage' => $_POST["1_Montage"],
        ':2_Intro' => $_POST["2_Intro"],
        ':2_Handlung' => $_POST["2_Handlung"],
        ':2_Perspektive' => $_POST["2_Perspektive"],
        ':2_Zeit' => $_POST["2_Zeit"],
        ':3_Intro' => $_POST["3_Intro"],
        ':3_Zeit' => $_POST["3_Zeit"],
        ':3_Spielraum' => $_POST["3_Spielraum"],
        ':3_Rolle' => $_POST["3_Rolle"],
        ':3_Regeln' => $_POST["3_Regeln"],
        ':3_Netzwerk' => $_POST["3_Netzwerk"],
        ':0_1Done' => $_POST["0_1Done"],
        ':0_2Done' => $_POST["0_2Done"],
        ':0_3Done' => $_POST["0_3Done"],
        ':0_Intro' => $_POST["0_Intro"],
        ':0_Fin' => $_POST["0_Fin"],
        ':Position' => $_POST["Position"],
        ':User' => $_POST["usr"],
        ':MobileUser' => $_POST["MobileUser"]
    ));

}

?>
```

Comment: As the error said, it is a server error (Code 500). So the error is more likely in the PHP code

Comment: it's probably not the solution, but I think you can (should?) have `data: {
    '1_Intro': $1Intro, 
    '1_Perspektive': $1Perspektive, 
    //... etc
}`

Comment: `is my data list too long` - who can tell ... how "big" is the request body?

Comment: Logs, do you hear it?

Comment: Did you make sure your file permissions are OK for the `dataform-to-database.php` file? Some hosts do not accept permissions that are too loose or have the wrong user and will return a 500 error if they are.

Comment: what is your backend db? MS SQL?

Answer (score 0):

500 - is a server error.

Maybe your real url without dot ?

```
 url: '/gameengine/dataform-to-database.php',
```

Or you have error in php script. Then show the code

Comment: Okay, so i tried it with the real url, and sent the data in object format. But i still get the same error.

Comment: Do you think it could help if I define some kind of DataType?

Answer (score 0):

In your ajax:`../` in url if you want to previous folder having `gameengine/dataform-to-database.php`

Also send your data in object format.Like this..

```
data = {$1Intro:$('#1Intro').val(),$1Perspektive:$('#1Perspektive').val(),...so on }
```

AJAX

```
$.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: '../gameengine/dataform-to-database.php',
     data: data,
     cache: false,
     error: function(e){
      console.log(e);
      },
      success: function(response){
        //alert(response);
      }
  });
```

Comment: A 505 means that `HTTP Version Not Supported` - but that's completely irrelevant

Comment: it is a 500, is that the same as 505.
the error says:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
update_database.js:51

Comment: why all the names are starting from number like 1_Intro... .There any restriction to use like this?

Comment: changed it, but it did not change the error...

i changed the method to GET to test what happens... and id does intressting things... it is appending   &_=1485445169527 is that normal?

Comment: GET http://www.matthiasnachbaur.com/webdoku/gameengine/dataform-to-database.php…Done3_0=0&Intro_0=1&Fin_0=0&Position=0&usr=17&MobileUser=0&_=1485446901262 500 (Internal Server Error)

Answer (score 0):

> So I think i somehow solved it by roling back my php version to 5.5.
>   Not a real solution, but now it works.

edit: not really... just dont get no error any more. still not working